# What happens when using `django-admin dumpdata` on a 'hot' or 'live' database?

Tags: django

When using the `django-admin dumpdata` command, what happens if the database is modified while the data is being exported? Is it possible for the data dump to be transactional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just running select queries. It will give whatever the database returns at the moment the select queries were run. There is no traction and no ability to add them. I don't think you would want to lock your site up anyways. You can see the source code here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py.